# Matlab Neural Network Structure

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I'm full newbie in neural networks. I generated NN in matlab. Further I need to know exact structure of this NN, because I need to implement it in Java(static connections and weights, no learning). Can you explain how to connect neurons and what math operations perform in each element?

NN params are next(taken from Matlab):

*iw{1,1} - Weight to layer 1 from intput 1*

```
[2.8574 -1.9207;
 1.7582 -1.2549;
 -4.5925 0.23236;
 12.0861 12.3701;
 2.503 -1.9321;
 -2.1422 2.6928]
```

*lw{2,1} - Weight to layer*

```
[-0.51977 5.3993 3.4349 5.2863 3.1976 -0.67102]
```

*b{1} - Bias to layer 1*

```
[-3.2811;
 -6.956;
 -3.0943;
 11.1103;
 0.14842;
 -3.3705]
```

*b{2} - Bias to layer 2*

```
[1.4657]
```

Transfer function `TANSIG`
 [image]
Greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

You have a NN that has 2 inputs, then a hidden layer of 6 neurons and an output layer of 1 neuron.

Each of the neuron in each layer, will take all the outputs from the previous one and multiply them by a number and offset the result by another.

The numbers you show are the numbers I mentioned.

For example, the neuron 1 from hidden layer will output `hidden1=2.8574*in1 -1.9207*in2-3.2811`. Then take whatever sigma function you are using and apply `hidden1=sigma(hidden1)`.

As another example, the output will be `out=-hidden1*0.51977+hidden2*5.3993+...-hidden6*0.67102+1.4657`

Comment: Thanks for reply. What about sigma function? Is it ignored or how to properly calculate it (maybe you can give a link) ? I didn't mentioned, but there are input ranges parameter when train nn in matlab, maybe they used in sigma.

Comment: @user2171669 I just assumed linear sigma function as you dint give any onformation about that. Just take the one you are using and input the output of each of the neurons to it.

Comment: Transfer function TANSIG. I found Continuous Tan-Sigmoid Function ( sigma(t)=(e^t-e^-t)/(e^t+e^-t) ), I hope it's it.

Comment: @user2171669 I guess it is ;) Give a try.